# Is it possible to access component variable when using component?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have an Angular's 7 component template as follows:

```
<div class="measure">
  <ng-content select="[label]"></ng-content>
  <div class="chart">
    <div class="state" [style.width.%]="progress">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <ng-content select="[value]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

As you can see `progress` is a variable in that component:

```
export class ProgressComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() current: any;
  @Input() maximum: any;
  @Input() minimum: any;

  progress: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    // Some code
  }
}
```

Is there a way to use the variable `progress` when using the component:

```
<mk-progress [minimum]="0" [maximum]="100" [current]="50" class="test">

  <span label>Label</span>

  <span value>{{progress}}%</span>

</mk-progress>
```

I am trying to use it in the code line:

```
 <span value>{{progress}}%</span>
```

Comment: You already have the `progress` variable available within the `ProgressComponent`. Why do you want to project it back into component? If you do want it, you can simply emit the value out and project it back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using `<ng-content>`.
However, you can achieve it by **projecting templates** instead of regular content.

Your component will then render these templates instead of `ng-content` via `<ng-container>`'s marked with an `ngTemplateOutlet` and set a context for these templates.

By using structural directives (adding a `*` in front of your directive), you are effectively wrapping your injected content with templates.

By using `@ContentChild` in your component, you can then reference these templates to instantiate them.

In order to access the template context when using your component, you can use the `let` keyword on the template to alias the `implicit` context and then reference it.

```
<div class="measure">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="labelTemplate; context: templateContext"></ng-container>
    <div class="chart">
        <div class="state" [style.width.%]="progress">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="valueTemplate; context: templateContext"></ng-container>
</div>
```

```
export class ProgressComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() current: any;
    @Input() maximum: any;
    @Input() minimum: any;

    @ContentChild(LabelDirective, { read: TemplateRef }) labelTemplate;
    @ContentChild(ValueDirective, { read: TemplateRef }) valueTemplate;

    progress: number;

    templateContext = { $implicit: this };

    ngOnInit() {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

```
<mk-progress [minimum]="0" [maximum]="100" [current]="50" class="test">
  <span *label>Label</span>
  <span *value="let item">{{ item.progress }}%</span>
</mk-progress>
```

This technique also allows you to provide default content if the templates are not provided:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="valueTemplate ? valueTemplate : defaultTemplate; context: templateContext">
</ng-container>
<ng-template #defaultTemplate>
  default thing to show
</ng-template>
```

See this [article](https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/) for more details.

Comment: I tried your code and checked the link you posted but it is not working. I created an example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-progress. Am I missing something?

Comment: You didn't declare the directives in the AppModule. It does work with the declarations, I wish angular would give us warnings for these errors, it took me a while to find it!

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to find the error and didn't notice that the directive were missing in module. I also wish angular could warn this situations.